# Why HIS tag is not detected in WB or dot blot?

Tags: western-blot, protein-expression

I would like to know why the recombinant protein with his tag at c terminus is not being detected neither in western blot or dot blot.

I'm trying to validate protein expression of four proteins. Three of the four proteins have no assigned protein family or domain (PFAM). The size of the proteins is small:

```
Locus   Nucleotide length   Protein size    Membrane features   Cloned  WB  Dot blot    Dot blot urea   COG
HPNK_06205  360 120 signal peptide  yes no  no  -   -
HPNK_09829  129 43  signal peptide  yes low low -   -
HPNK_10446  756 252 transmembrane   yes no  no  -   COG1175 ABC-type sugar transport systems, permease components
HPNK_11461  264 88  signal peptide  yes yes yes -   -
```

Next steps:

-Discard possible his tag hidding by adding urea to dot blot.

-Revise annotation for the proteins. Since all are annotated as hypothetical proteins, maybe there is an alternative annotation that could lead to longer proteins and maybe more stable products.

Comment: Some troubleshootings can be found here, pointing to hidden his tag. https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_am_I_not_able_to_detect_6_HIS_tag